# Display entire column value as password field in jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables, passwords

Have a jquery datatable which will show the id and password contained in a database table.

**HTML:**

```
<table id="pwdTable">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>PWD</th>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

The table is populated via ajax call.

```
$("pwdTable").DataTable({
ajax:{get the data},
columns:[
{
"data":"id"
},
{
"data":"pwd",
"type":"password"
}
]
});
```

**Question:**
How do I show the password column data as ***(normal password field representation). Tried "type":"password" but that doesn't show the field in the desired format.
Expected outcome:
[image]
Also have to add option to add delete the row, which is accomplished. Need to hide/show the password with the help of Hide/View button at the end of each row. Any suggestions on it will be helpful.

Comment: I expect someone may show you how to do these things using DataTables - it's certainly possible. But storing raw passwords in a database table is generally a very bad idea - and being able to display those same passwords in a web page is also a very bad idea. There should be no need to store the password itself - or be able to retrieve it from whatever hashed, salted representation you _do_ store.

Comment: @andrewjames Agreed on that we shouldn't be storing the passwords and display the passwords, but actually that's the requirement :) . The access to this web page will be restricted to certain set of admins.

Comment: Understood. Perhaps a purpose-built password management tool (with support for team usage) may be a safer way to meet the reqirement.